# Terminal keeps giving error: 'node: --experimental-workerexport is not allowed in NODE_OPTIONS'

Tags: node.js, macos

My terminal on Mac (Osx 10.15.1) keeps giving me:

`node: --experimental-workerexport is not allowed in NODE_OPTIONS`

It doesn't matter which folder I'm in, it always gives me this error if I try to do something with Node.

Node version: v13.6.0 /
NVM version: 0.35.2

Comment: Please try this with stable version v12.14 of node

Comment: Already tried this, no changes unfortunately

Answer (score 3):

Someone somewhere has set environment variable `NODE_OPTIONS` to something like

```
NODE_OPTIONS='--experimental-workerexport'
```

The list of options allowed in `NODE_OPTIONS` is limited: https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v16.x/docs/api/cli.html#cli_node_options_options

When Node.js starts and encounters disallowed option, it complains and exits.

There are two possible situations:

1. Environment variable is just exported once and not persisted. Restarting OS will help.
2. Environment variable is set every time after restart (e.g. in `~/.bashrc`). You should find where `NODE_OPTIONS` is set and remove any disallowed options from it.