# --openssl-legacy-provider not allowed in NODE_OPTIONS in Dockerfile Node 14 Alpine

Tags: node.js, docker

My dockerfile fails to build with the following error:

```
node: --openssl-legacy-provider is not allowed in NODE_OPTIONS
```

This is my dockerfile:

```
FROM node:14-alpine as build

RUN apk update
RUN apk --no-cache --virtual build-dependencies add \
    python3 \
    g++ 

WORKDIR /app

# Add the source code to app
COPY ./js /app

# Install all the dependencies
RUN yarn install --frozen-lockfile
RUN yarn bootstrap

# Generate the build of the application
RUN NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider yarn build

FROM node:14-alpine AS runner
WORKDIR /app

ENV NODE_ENV production

RUN addgroup -g 1001 -S nodejs
RUN adduser -S nextjs -u 1001
```

Running yarn build works with the following package.json but just not in the docker build:

```
"scripts" {
     "build": "NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider lerna run build",
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To resolve build issues in my Dockerfile, I added the following line:

```
ENV NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider
```

`--openssl-legacy-provider` is a specific option that instructs Node.js to use the legacy OpenSSL provider for cryptographic operations. Be cautious about security implications! using the legacy OpenSSL provider might not always be the most secure option. You probably need to update the packages you are using.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Looking into your docker instruction, you are using NodeJs v14:

```
FROM node:14-alpine as build
```

This version does not support the flag you are using which was added in: v17.0.0, v16.17.0

Using the latest version of NodeJs or an updated version (after v16.17.00) would solve the problem.

Related docs from NodeJs: https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#--openssl-legacy-provider

Meanwhile this question is similar to the next questions:

- [node: --import is not allowed in NODE_OPTIONS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77570713/node-import-is-not-allowed-in-node-options)
- [electron: --openssl-legacy-provider is not allowed in NODE_OPTIONS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74759898/electron-openssl-legacy-provider-is-not-allowed-in-node-options)
- [node: --openssl-legacy-provider is not allowed in NODE_OPTIONS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72866798/node-openssl-legacy-provider-is-not-allowed-in-node-options)
- [--openssl-legacy-provider is not allowed in NODE_OPTIONS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77201974/openssl-legacy-provider-is-not-allowed-in-node-options)
- [Terminal keeps giving error: 'node: --experimental-workerexport is not allowed in NODE_OPTIONS'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59802779/terminal-keeps-giving-error-node-experimental-workerexport-is-not-allowed-i)