# Error message "node: --openssl-legacy-provider is not allowed in NODE_OPTIONS"

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules

This problem appeared after an update, `sudo apt upgrade`, on [Ubuntu 20.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_20.04_LTS_(Focal_Fossa)) (Focal Fossa).

Previously, I worked on versions Node.js v18.0.0 and npm 8.7.0, but after the update there was a problem. I ran command `nvm install node --reinstall-packages-from=node`, but it did not help.

Now I use npm v8.12.1 and Node.js v18.4.0.

When running the command `npm start`, I receive the message:

```
> mini-app@0.0.0 start
> cross-env PORT=10888 HTTPS=false react-scripts start --openssl-legacy-provider

node: --openssl-legacy-provider is not allowed in NODE_OPTIONS
```

part of a file, *[package.json](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/configuring-npm/package-json/)*, looks like this :

```json
 "scripts": {
    "start": "cross-env PORT=10888 HTTPS=false react-scripts start --openssl-legacy-provider",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "predeploy": "npm run build",
    "deploy": "vk-miniapps-deploy",
    "tunnel": "vk-tunnel --insecure=1 --http-protocol=https --ws-protocol=wss --host=localhost --port=10888"
  },
```

I went back to version npm 8.7.0, `npm install -g npm@8.7.0`, but now even the output of Node.js version  shows the same error:

```
node -v
```

Output:

```
node: --openssl-legacy-provider is not allowed in NODE_OPTIONS
```

Attempt to update:

```
nvm install 12.13.0
```

Output:

```
v12.13.0 is already installed.
Now using node v12.13.0 (npm v)
```

Comment: if someone ends up here who have `lerna` configuration then directly jumping on particular package setup, make sure you `install`, `prepare` and `build` all packages first. No need of any further changes required for `--openssl-legacy-provider` if it was already there

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try to perform an unset on the NODE_OPTIONS production variable. It can be done from the command line.

Your Node.js version seems already up-to-date (version 18). A similar problem was already treated and solved according to the GitHub page *[Running code via CLI triggers error: --openssl-legacy-provider is not allowed in NODE_OPTIONS #136599](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/136599)*.

Comment: thanks, that helped! i also used the command `nvm install 10` to fix the error : `ERROR: npm is known not to run on Node.js v10.19.0 You'll need to upgrade to a newer Node.js version in order to use this version of npm. You can find the latest version at https://nodejs.org/`

Answer (score 88):

I ran into this on macOS. From [Terminal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_(macOS)#Terminal), I ran `export` to check my environment variables and saw that `NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider` had been set. I then simply ran `unset NODE_OPTIONS` and then was able to use Node.js again.

Comment: This really help me, thanks! I had to execute the command inside my docker console, but it was fine!

Answer (score 46):

#### Just run this command

```
unset NODE_OPTIONS
```

Comment: or in Windows: set NODE_OPTIONS=

Comment: This removes an environment variable. There must be more to it. Answers on Stack Overflow are expected to be standalone / self-contained. E.g., *where* does it go? In what sequence? When?

Answer (score 34):

For me unsetting NODE_OPTIONS alone didn't solve the problem. I had to use

```
nvm use v18
```

to solve the issue.

Comment: Life saver. But I think I had to run `unset NODE_OPTIONS` before.

Comment: on mac, this solved my problem

Comment: On mac solved my problem as well

Comment: On mac, this was the issue for me. I did not have `NODE_OPTIONS` set so running `nvm use v18` was the only thing I had to do.

Answer (score 27):

## A Simple way through NPM.

We can set the SSL legacy option in the *.npmrc* file.

In my case Node.JS v18 with npm v9.

##### Add or edit the *.npmrc* file in your project folder and add the option:

```
node-options="--openssl-legacy-provider"
```

### Advantages:

- It can be managed per project
- The *.npmrc* file in the project will remind us that the project needs to be updated.
- If that appears in another project on the server we will still have the error.

Comment: I resorted to using yarn. Not a solution if you must use npm, but this allowed me to continue.

> yarn install

Done

Comment: Hi @HenkKruger, sorry I'm using NPM so I didn't search for yarn.

Comment: Best solution for sure!

Comment: @Michaël you're a life-saver. I needed to boot up a 10 year old project in a local environment and this worked without making the rest of my projects insecure.

Answer (score 21):

On Linux, you need to edit your */etc/ssl/openssl.cnf* file to uncomment a few lines that will enable legacy provider support.

I am on [Fedora](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fedora_Linux) 36; I had to change these lines:

```
##[provider_sect]
##default = default_sect
##legacy = legacy_sect
##
##[default_sect]
##activate = 1
##
##[legacy_sect]
##activate = 1
```

to:

```
[provider_sect]
default = default_sect
legacy = legacy_sect

[default_sect]
activate = 1

[legacy_sect]
activate = 1
```

Comment: Time saver, got this problem on Fedora 36 too. Thanks mate!

Comment: Just complementing these lines did not yet do the trick, do I need to restart something?

Comment: ok, I had to uncomment the section, then delete the `node_modules` and run `npm install` again. Then it even worked without `--openssl-legacy-provider` since I'm still running on node v16.14.0 on Fedora 36.

Comment: didn't work for me at all, so the solution was to install the nvm and use it to install the latest v16.
https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm

Comment: didn't work any solution except every time exportin node_options with flag.
It happens when change node version in nvm from 14.17 to 16. after then, event downgrading to 14.21 is not solution for me (using yarn, not npm)

Answer (score 10):

#### Quick fix

You can try to downgrade the version. But as a quick fix, you can do the below options.

**On [Unix-like](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix-like) systems (Linux, macOS, [Git Bash](https://superuser.com/questions/1053633/what-is-git-bash-for-windows-anyway), etc.):**

```
export NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider
```

**On the Windows command prompt:**

```
set NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider
```

**In PowerShell:**

```
$env:NODE_OPTIONS = "--openssl-legacy-provider"
```

[Read more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69692842/error-message-error0308010cdigital-envelope-routinesunsupported)

Answer (score 8):

I'm running macOS. I previously had Node.js version 18, which had this issue in my Node.js project:

```
Error message "error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported"
```

I downgraded the Node.js version to 16 LTS, and then it had this error:

```
node: --openssl-legacy-provider is not allowed in NODE_OPTIONS
```

The issue resolved by simply running the following command in the terminal.

```
unset NODE_OPTIONS
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue with [React Native](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/React_(JavaScript_library)#React_Native), *./gradlew assembleRelease*.

I solved this by downgrading Node.js version to v18.17.0 and setting Node.js options as `--openssl-legacy-provider`

**Commands**

```
nvm install v18

nvm use v18

export NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider
```

Answer (score 2):

Two ways to fix it:

#### Way 1

Try resetting `NODE_OPTIONS` by running the following command:

```
export NODE_OPTIONS=""
```

#### Way 2

Upgrade to Node.js 18

```
nvm use v18
```

Answer (score 2):

Using [Node.js](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Node.js) 18.18.2 and `export NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider` to the start script:

```json
"scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "export NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider && react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint ."
  },
```

solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

The previous answers were good suggestions. However, what worked for me was commenting the entry in the *.npmrc* file located in my project folder as shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pX70h.png).

Comment: Please review *[Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)* (e.g., *"Images should only be used to illustrate problems that* ***can't be made clear in any other way,*** *such as to provide screenshots of a user interface."*) and [do the right thing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75804860/edit) (it covers answers as well). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing Error on `yarn start`. Error screenshot is attached below

[image]

Now I fixed this by following steps:
open **pakage.json** and change script object

```
  "scripts": {
  "android": "react-native run-android",
  "build_debug": "react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res",
  "ios": "react-native run-ios",
  "start": "cross-env NODE_OPTIONS= --openssl-legacy-provider start",
  "test": "jest",
  "lint": "eslint .",
  "android_apk": "npx react-native run-android --variant=release"
  
  },
```

**with this**

```
"scripts": {
    
        "android": "react-native run-android",
        "ios": "react-native run-ios",
        "build": "react-native run-android --mode=release",
        "lint": "eslint .",
        "start": "react-native start",
        "test": "jest"
      },
```

And second step I performed is that created a **.env** file in my **React Native Project root directory** and place the below code in it

```
NODE_OPTIONS="--openssl-legacy-provider"
```

And again run `yarn start` command

Comment: Please review *[Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)* (e.g., *"Images should only be used to illustrate problems that* ***can't be made clear in any other way,*** *such as to provide screenshots of a user interface."*) and [do the right thing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76920604/edit) (it covers answers as well). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I was on [Node.js](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Node.js) 16 and I just upgraded to Node.js v18 (NODE_OPTIONS may be a red herring).

Also, the variable was not exported to the env (so there wasn't any way to unset it), but it was part of the command (in [package.json](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/configuring-npm/package-json/)), i.e., "serve": "set NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider && vue-cli-service serve"

Answer (score -1):

Update NVM to v18, and then unset NODE_OPTIONS.

It will be OK!

Comment: This answer appears to be a duplicate of one already provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74192831/6951294).

Comment: Re *"Update NVM to v18"*: How exactly?

Comment: Re *"Update NVM to v18"*: Do you mean *"Update* ***Node.js*** *to v18"*?

Comment: Is this a completely bogus answer?