# --openssl-legacy-provider is not allowed in NODE_OPTIONS

Tags: node.js, angular, github-actions, angular-cli

On GitHub Actions getting the below error:

```
Run npm run build

> app@0.0.0 build D:\a\ma-test-app\ma-test-app\app
> SET NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider && ng build

node: --openssl-legacy-provider is not allowed in NODE_OPTIONS
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 9
npm ERR! app@0.0.0 build: `SET NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider && ng build`
npm ERR! Exit status 9
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the pidgeon@0.0.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

Tried to `set NODE_OPTIONS=` as below but does not work:

```yaml
 angular-build:
    name: angular build
    runs-on: windows-latest

      - name: Install Dependencies
        working-directory: ./app
        run: |
          npm install --force
          
      - name: Unset Node Options
        working-directory: ./app
        run: |
          set NODE_OPTIONS=-
          
      - name: Build
        working-directory: ./app
        run: |
          npm run build
```

I saw most of the answers are pointing to Mac/Linux. But I could hardly find any options on GitHub Actions.

Comment: `set NODE_OPTIONS=-` in a previous step isn't going to override `SET NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider` at the start of the `script` you're running. Why do you need the `--openssl-legacy-provider` flag just to do an `ng build` anyway?

Comment: ng build is not working without that in local. New to this project and they have set in package.json file the same. When I set the pipeline it's giving this error.

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72866798/node-openssl-legacy-provider-is-not-allowed-in-node-options. Seems like unsetting `NODE_OPTIONS` should work. Please edit and update your workflow to show the runner you're using i.e. `runs-on`.

Comment: @Azeem, it runs on windows_latest. Cannot use Unset.

Comment: @AjayManagaon: Please add that in your question. Something like `env: NODE_OPTIONS: ''` should work.

Comment: Tried it, its the same error.

Comment: However you try to unset it (not that it's actually set to start with) it's going to be immediately _re_-set beforehand, because that's the first half of the build script. The fact that you're also forcing the install isn't a good sign for the health of this pipeline up to now.

Comment: this option seems to be appeared in nodejs 18+. I think you are using the older version where legacy ssl is basically the default option. And that is why you can just omit this option, or update your nodejs

Comment: This is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72866798/node-openssl-legacy-provider-is-not-allowed-in-node-options What worked with me on windows was using the latest version of node and LTS version. What version does the runner use?