# node: --import is not allowed in NODE_OPTIONS

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon

I had this issue when I tried to run refined-github extension in the development environment:

The error code was:

```bash
node: --import is not allowed in NODE_OPTIONS
ERROR: "build:webpack" exited with 9.
```

**node version:** v16

**OS:** Windows 11

I tried the next without success:

- unsetting the node_options
- changing node version to 18

Checked the next questions for guidance without success as well:

- [electron: --openssl-legacy-provider is not allowed in NODE_OPTIONS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74759898/electron-openssl-legacy-provider-is-not-allowed-in-node-options) : this one did not provide much information
- [node: --openssl-legacy-provider is not allowed in NODE_OPTIONS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72866798/node-openssl-legacy-provider-is-not-allowed-in-node-options) : at this question they suggested the unset, and using version 18 which did not work
- [--openssl-legacy-provider is not allowed in NODE_OPTIONS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77201974/openssl-legacy-provider-is-not-allowed-in-node-options) : did not have answers.
- [Terminal keeps giving error: 'node: --experimental-workerexport is not allowed in NODE_OPTIONS'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59802779/terminal-keeps-giving-error-node-experimental-workerexport-is-not-allowed-i) : dead question for three years
- [--openssl-legacy-provider not allowed in NODE_OPTIONS in Dockerfile Node 14 Alpine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71273965/openssl-legacy-provider-not-allowed-in-node-options-in-dockerfile-node-14-alpi) which was for docker.

Comment: https://github.com/refined-github/refined-github/blob/2fcbc2b28b6ca8c241c0411887e53a61b9e33e1e/package.json#L131-L134

Comment: Thanks, yeah I did not know that till I searched for an hour, I thought it would worth to add it to StackOverFlow for other people who might face the same issue.

here is the maintainer comment and related PR: 
https://github.com/refined-github/refined-github/pull/7112#issuecomment-1826982284

Answer (score 0):

Looking into the [nodeJs docs](https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#--importmodule) at 29.11.2023 it's showing that this feature was added in NodeJs version 19.00.00, 18.18.00 updating my NodeJs version to the LTS (v20) helped with that and solved the issue.

the docs link: https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#--importmodule

web archive version for the same day: https://web.archive.org/web/20231128140137/https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#--importmodule